# Express Routes - Issues with multiple files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I'm starting to learn Node.js with Express, but i've got few issues with the routing system.

In my app.js (my main file), i have :

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var admin = require('./routes/admin');
...
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/admin, admin);
```

In the index.js :

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', {
    title: 'Express'
  });
});
```

The root url work great, and it return correctly the jade template 'index'.

I'm trying to do the same thing, in a different file, for an 'admin' template (wich is in './routes/admin'). 
There is the point, when i go to the localhost:5000/admin (for exemple), it return a 404 error.

There is my admin.js file :

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/admin', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('admin', {
    title: 'Connexion'
  });
});
```

Both of index.js and admin.js contain `module.exports = router;`

If someone got an idea or want to comment, you're welcome.

Thanks a lot (and forgive my english !)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to route this page localhost:5000/admin/admin. app.use('/admin, admin); means that all function in admin.js will be called by this request localhost:5000/admin/...
So If you want to render admin.jade with this request localhost:5000/admin, you should insert this function in 
**routes/index**

```
router.get('/admin', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('admin', {
    title: 'Connexion'
  });
});
```

**or in routes/admin insert this function:**

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('admin', {
    title: 'Connexion'
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks you for your answer, it works. But @dc2 said something interesting : is it a probleme to call `express` and `Router` intance in each file ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be that you are instantiating multiple instances of `express` and its `Router`, one in each routes file. You'll want one `Router` in your `app.js` file, and each of the separate routes file should refer to this single instance.

As one idea, you could pass in your router in `app.js` to each of your `routes` files:

```
// app.js
var admin = require('./routes/admin');
admin.init(router);
```

And then in your `admin.js` file:

```
var init = function(router) {
  exports.router = router;

  exports.router.get('/admin', function(req, res, next) { 
    // ...
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be: `-app.use('/admin', admin);` (with quotes around the first part only) and not: `-app.use('/admin, admin);`